# How to get google chrome current URL using react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, tabs, geturl

Here's sample code

`useEffect(() => {     // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef     chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, (tabs) => {       setCurrentUrl(tabs[0].url);     });   }, []);`

I could get the current URL using about code

Comment: Could you elaborate on what your question is? If your goal is to get the url, then you can do so with Web APIs that aren’t Chrome specific like `window.location.href`. Is there a reason why you need this to be browser specific?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.